# Fortran Floating Error while performing summation within DO loop?

Tags: floating-point, sum, double-precision

I have four double precision real numbers (n1, n2, n3, & n4) in an array (n).

The weird thing that when I calculate the sum of these four numbers within
a DO loop and then calculate the sum directly I don't get the same exact number!

Note that I am changing the sequence of the numbers. for example during the Do loop I go n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 but in the direct sum I go n1 + n3 + n2 + n4. Both should give the same number, but when I subtract the two results I don't get zero, instead I get a very tiny number (x10^-21)!

Here is my Code:

```
PROGRAM SumFourNo
REAL(KIND=DP) :: n(4), n_sum
INTEGER       :: i

n(1) = 9.259259259259259E-006
n(2) = 4.629629629629630E-006
n(3) = 9.259259259259259E-006
n(4) = 4.629629629629630E-006
n_sum = 0.0_DP

DO i = 1 , 4
    n_sum = n_sum + n(i)
ENDDO

WRITE(*,*) 'Check =', (n(1)+n(3)+n(2)+n(4)) - n_sum

ENDPROGRAM SumFourNo
```

Of course my code is way bigger than this but I don't want to confuse you so I showed you only this portion of it.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic is not associative like real math. The order of summation matters, and a good number of papers have been written on how to achieve accurate results in the general case. You might want to read this [primer on floating-point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Note that a difference of `10^-21` in numbers with magnitude of about `10^-6` is a difference in the 15th significant figure, right at the limit of 64-bit IEEE floating-point precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classical rounding error problem. Floating-point addition doesn't obey the usual mathematical rules. In particular, `(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)` does not hold.

If `10^-21` is too much of an error for you, look up Kahan summation. In short, that keeps track of the accumulated rounding errors in summation.

Comment: Thanks, Kahan summation eliminated the error for me.